# Regular expression is not working

Tags: sed

I am using the below the sed removing string

sed -ie 's/^\s*worker..*.balance_workers=(.*)pgnode2(.*)/worker..*.balance_workers=\1\2/' worker.txt

My content is:

`#worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=
worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2
worker.stgpgloadbalancer.sticky_session=1

worker.stgadminloadbalancer.type=lb
worker.stgadminloadbalancer.balance_workers=stgadmin2,stgadmin1
worker.stgadminloadbalancer.sticky_session=1`

I want to remove pgnode1 from the above expression
Result:

worker..*.balance_workers=pgnode1,

Expected result:
worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,

Answer (score 1):

You're missing escape characters.

Try:

```
sed -ie 's/worker\.stgpgloadbalancer\.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2\?\(.*\)/worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode2/' worker.txt
```

**UPDATE**

You changed the initial regex but now (besides missing the initial / from sed you're using () without escapes as well, which will those characters will be seen as from part of the pattern to find).

If you wish only to remove pgnode1 you can simply do the following:

```
sed -ie 's/worker\.stgpgloadbalancer\.balance_workers=\(.*\)pgnode1,\(.*\)/worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=\1\2/' worker.txt
```

First you escape everything correctly with backslashes.
Then you create two groups one before pgnode1 and another one after pgnode1.

You then proceed to substitute the property with group1 followed by group2, removing pgnode1.

**UPDATE 2**

If you want to avoid that commented lines may be changed change say that the start needs to be either spaces or nothing like the following:

```
sed -ie 's/^\s*worker\.stgpgloadbalancer\.balance_workers=\(.*\)pgnode1,\(.*\)/worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=\1\2/' worker.txt
```

**UPDATE 3**

You really need to improve on how to explain your requirements in a single question :-) How many edits to the question have you already done? Well that doesn't really matter...

If you want to match all properties in the format worker.xxxxxx.balance_workers where xxxxxx is variable what you have to do is create a group for it so you can then replace it in your expression.

Like the following:

```
sed -ie 's/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\(.*\)pgnode1,\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\3/'
```

We've basicaly removed the expression stgpgloadbalancer and replaced it with a group that allows anything `\(.*\)`. Since this is the first group we then use `\1` in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Hey I have to just remove the pgnode1 from  worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2

Comment: Do you want to remove all reference to pgnode1 in the file or only in the property worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers ?

Comment: i just to remove pgnode1 from this line worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2

Comment: @HarjeetPahuja updated the answer with regex that removes pgnode1 from that line keeping all other nodes.

Comment: I just to remove pgnode1 worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2 this line only not in #worker.stgpgloadbalancer.balance_workers=pgnode1,pgnode2 and i dont use stgpgloadbalancer because i have to do same for worker.stgadminloadbalancer.balance_workers=stgadmin2,stgadmin1  so everytime i have to hard code this vaule

Comment: @HarjeetPahuja you had not specified that in your initial question. Made a second update that ensures that either you have spaces or your property at the start of the line ensuring that no commented lines are caught

Comment: As you can see my regex i don't want to use stgpgloadbalancer and in your regx you are using sed -ie 's/^\s*worker\.stgpgloadbalancer\.balance_workers=(.*‌​1;pgnode1,(.*‌​1;/worker.stgpgloadb‌​alancer.balance_work‌​ers=\1\2/' worker.txt

Comment: @HarjeetPahuja update the naswer replacing stgpgloadb‌ by a group

Comment: Thanks It's working fine for me but again I have to add the same pgnode1 on same location

Comment: Now i have to add string on same location and i am using the below regx but its not working for me   "sed -ie 's/^\s*worker\.\(.*\)\.balance_workers=\pgnode1\(.*\)/worker.\1.balance_workers=\2\(.*\)/' worker.txt"

Comment: @HarjeetPahuja You state in your question you want to remove pgnde1 in your question, now you say you want to keep it. Which one is it? Please take a step back, think thoroughly what you really need and properly edit your question. Also add the full worker.txt as it should be **after** regex parse.

Comment: i have to perform both operation first i have to remove then add because i am performing some deployment process in my task.So remove option is working fine but for adding option i am getting ambiguity of regex.

Comment: @HarjeetPahuja and where was that stated in your question? You're going off scope with his conversation! You won't be able to do it with a  regex, because you have properties in the format worker.xxxx.balance_workers that didn't had a pgnode1 if you add via regex you'll add to all of them, for example, stgadminloadbalancer property would get the pgnode1. Best scenario is to first grep the file for pgnode1 and store in a second file then use that temporary file to re-place only those specific properties. And please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions.